# Merge [unity3d-5] and [unity5] tags (or synonymize or delete)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

The [unity3d-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-5) and [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tags are being used for the same purpose. Can these be merged or made into synonyms?

Alternatively, these may not be needed at all. I'm not convinced tagging a question as related to Unity 5 actually adds anything; if it's a Unity question, and it's about something introduced in a specific version, we may not need a tag on StackOverflow to tell us which version it's from.

Comment: I would agree with your latter paragraph. Even though there has been a fair amount of change between versions, I don't particularly see that a Unity 5 specific tag adds a whole lot of info that couldn't be put into the question itself.

Comment: Both these tags are now synonyms of [tag:unity3d], as of Oct '17

Comment: @Rob Could you look at this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365791/dissolve-unitys-union-unity3d-and-unity5

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I didn't actually apply the synonyms.. I was just going through the backlog to mark requests completed/declined. This particular synonym was applied in October 2017