# Dissolve unity's union: [unity3d] and [unity5]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

[unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) refers to the game engine, while [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) refers, if anything, to version 5 of that engine. I see no reason for these to be synonyms, specially with Unity 2017 being so different to Unity 5.

[unity3d-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-5) exists as a separate tag, so I believe the synonym went wrong.

How it is now:

- [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) synonym to [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5)
- [unity3d-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-5) without synonyms

How it should be:

- [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) as a standalone tag
- [unity3d-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-5) should be synonym to [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5)

We should also decide whether the new tags would be [unity2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2017)/[unity2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2018) or [unity3d-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2017)/[unity3d-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2018)

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303925/merge-unity3d-5-and-unity5-tags-or-synonymize-or-delete?rq=1

Comment: The recently added "[unity-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-2017)" tag does seem somewhat redundant in 2018. Just Unity or Unity3D. I fail to see the benefit of multiple tags here.

Comment: @Lece Unity 2017 is one product, Unity 2018 is another. There are huge (extreme) differences in the .NET and c# version between Unity 5 and 2017.

Comment: I actually created and voted to marge those two. The questions and answers were hard to find when they were separate tags. There is really no major difference between these two other than new features. There is also no need to have Unity2017, 2018... tags. This is like having Maya 2017, 2018, 2019 ... tags . Where  does it end?