# Which tag should be used: [unity5] or [unity3d]?

Tags: discussion, tags

So as far as I'm aware, there is a [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag and a [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tag. While the [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tag is surely outdated, what is the difference in the 2 tags, and why would you use one over the other?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms [tag:unity5] is set as a synonym

Comment: @SurajRao Funny enough, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365791/424903) seeks to disband that synonym.

Comment: @Gimby that does bring some perspective but still doesnt really clarify the question since at present OP would get `unity3d` tag either way. I do not have the technical knowledge on this to discuss whether it _should_ be a synonym or not

Comment: @SurajRao its a mess, that's for sure. There seem to be subsequent problems of product renaming (unity -> unity3d) and generic product tags being mixed and matched with version-specific tags.

Comment: Why is there not one tag for unity in general instead there are several tags and why would you create version specific tags as they will be outdated with every update