# Can't add a tag to an existing question?

Tags: support, tags, editor

When trying to add a tag to [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56251444), after saving the changes, nothing happens. Is this a bug? If not, ***why is there no message***?

[image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303925/merge-unity3d-5-and-unity5-tags-or-synonymize-or-delete?rq=1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) is a synonym of [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).

This means by adding [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) as a tag, you’re adding [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) instead.

Your question already has the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag, and it can’t be added again, so nothing happens. That’s not a bug but the intended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like a bug. Why is there no message about this?

Comment: Eh... Synonyms have always been silently converted without any error messages for duplicate tags. If you want an error/info message when a tag has been added twice (or a way to make it more visible you're using a synonym and not the real thing), I suggest opening a [meta-tag:feature-request] explaining why this would benefit the site.

Comment: @ErikA that sounds reasonable. Both making the feature request and the request itself. I was certainly confused by the behaviour shown. I don't use Unity, so perhaps some familiarity would have clued me in, but on the other hand I can see this being even more confusing to newcomers if they try to add tags that are synonyms but are silently swallowed.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, but that is also in part because people make a really quick jump to labeling something they don't understand as a bug. That quick jump is not too great for reasoning about things properly.

Comment: @VLAZ It can be a feature request to tell users about tag synonyms because then they might be worried if this happens in future and more meta dupe questions will not arise.