# Unity tags broken

Tags: support

I've noticed that if you use the [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) or [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) tags on your post, they are automatically changed to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) upon posting, or at least I have noticed it happening to my posts. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: Maybe default to "I don't understand" rather than "broken!". You may have signed up 42 days ago, but Stack Overflow has been around for over a decade.

Comment: Link to original synonymization request: [Merge `unity3d-5` and `unity5` tags (or synonymize or delete)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303925/merge-unity3d-5-and-unity5-tags-or-synonymize-or-delete).

Comment: Gimby, I assumed it was a bug in like an update or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) and [unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity5) are tag synonyms i.e. if you use them they are basically replaced by the tag they are a synonym of, as you've discovered by experiment.

You can see them listed as synonyms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms)

More information about tag synonyms is available from the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)